# Calling postgresql function from dotnet6

Tags: .net, postgresql

My PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test() 
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE
    ref1 refcursor;
BEGIN

OPEN ref1 FOR 
    Select * from public.testTable;

RETURN ref1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My C# dotnet6 code:

```
string connString = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Port={4}", Host, "testDB", Username, Password, Port);
NpgsqlConnection pgCon = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
pgCon.Open();
string strCmd = @"select * from public.fn_test();";
NpgsqlCommand pgCmd = new NpgsqlCommand(strCmd, pgCon);
NpgsqlDataReader pgDr = pgCmd.ExecuteReader(); //This returns <unnamed portal 1>
```

Question:
How to read values from <unnamed portal 1>?

PostgreSQL version: 14.5

Dotnet version: 6

Visual Studio 2022

Thank you!

Comment: Why return a ref cursor? Functions declared as `returns table(...)` are typically much easier to work with (you just run a `select * from some_function()`)

Comment: Read the docs here [plpgsql returning cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-USING) *43.7.3.5. Returning Cursors*. Hint: see `CREATE FUNCTION reffunc(refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS ...`.

Comment: 1) Add code to question properly formatted. 2) Does that mean it works for you?